# Is this relation transitive

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

My book states that $A= \{(1, 2), (2, 1)\}$ isn't transitive.

It also states that $B=\{(2, 1), (1, 2)\}$ is transitive and symmetric but not reflective.

I think that $A = B$ thus this is a contradiction. I think this $A$ and $B$ are equivalent because these are unordered sets of ordered pairs.

Which is correct and if $B$ is incorrect then what is a transitive, symmetric but not reflexive set?

Comment: In what way are $A$ and $B$ relations and not sets?

Comment: What is the relation exactly? And, why are elements in the sets repeated? Do they have some particular significance?

Comment: Why write $\{(1,2)\}$ as $\{(1,2),(1,2)\}$? That strikes me as highly perverse.

Comment: please note the updated numbers, I made a mistake in writing the question because I was too focused on the formatting

Comment: Now, relation $B$ is also not transitive since $2$ is related to $1$ and $1$ is related to $2$, but $2$ is not related to $2$.

Comment: Now **we** are confused... $A=B$ and **not** transitive because neither $(1,1)$ nor $(2,2)$ are in it.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA that's why I asked the question as I figured that something is wrong here. And therefore the last part of the question about one that is transitive and symmetric but not reflexive

Comment: I suspect this question has been edited in a way that invalidates a lot of the comments.  As written, both $A,B$ appear to be relations on the set $\{1,2\}$.  As such they are the same relation as we have $1\sim 2$ and $2\sim 1$ and no other relations.

Comment: You made a mistake, the author of the answer below made a mistake, the author of your book made a mistake... Conclusion : sometimes humans make mistakes.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, I still really would like to know what is correct now that I know that these answers in my book are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly, $A\neq B$. However, it is true that both relations must have the same properties. What happens is that neither of them is reflexive or transitive and both of them are symmetric.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos please note the updated numbers, I made a mistake in writing the question because I was too focused on the formatting. They where as written clearly unequal.

Comment: @TarickWelling I've edited my answer, in order to adapt it to the new version of the question.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thus the ordering in $A$ and $B$ matters for equivalence? And what would be a transitive, symmetric but not reflexive logical sentence? Seeing as my answer from my textbook is wrong.

Comment: The order matters if the question is “is $A=B$”? But it doesn't matter if the goal is to study the properties of the relation. So, yes, the answer from your textbook is wrong.

Comment: I apologize, I should've been clearer about what amount of equality would suffice.